Error loading "libmpich.dylib" using Python ctypes on MacOS
I am trying to load mpich library in python using ctypes. But getting the following error. OSError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/libmpich.dylib, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace '_ADIOI_Datarep_head'
Python 3.12.3 (main, Apr  9 2024, 08:09:14) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4)] on darwin
>>> from ctypes import cdll
>>> cdll.LoadLibrary("/opt/homebrew/lib/libmpich.dylib")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ctypes/__init__.py", line 460, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/ctypes/__init__.py", line 379, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/libmpich.dylib, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace '_ADIOI_Datarep_head'

otools show that the dylib has dependency on "/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib". The libSystem.B.dylib file is not is that directory and I was reading that in new MacOS, this dynamic library has been rolled into the dynamic linker shared cache. Any idea how to resolve this issue?
user@machine: otool -L libmpich.dylib  
libmpich.dylib:
    /opt/homebrew/opt/mpich/lib/libmpi.12.dylib (compatibility version 17.0.0, current version 17.0.0)
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mpich/4.2.0/lib/libpmpi.12.dylib (compatibility version 17.0.0, current version 17.0.0)
    /opt/homebrew/opt/hwloc/lib/libhwloc.15.dylib (compatibility version 23.0.0, current version 23.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1336.61.1)

user@machine: ll /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
ls: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib: No such file or directory


might be slightly offtopic but i found similar sort of issue being reported to MacPorts - essentially somewhere up in libtool - could be related ?  Your output shows its off from homebrew. I'd try first to downgrade to mpich 4.1.0 on homebrew or try the build of macports - or compile yourself.

https://trac.macports.org/ticket/61584

I tried compiling "mpich" from source code. Still got same error.

Looks like the C Library can be loaded without error using ctypes.CDLL given ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL as additional argument.
>>> import ctypes
>>> a = ctypes.CDLL("/opt/homebrew/lib/libmpich.dylib", ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)
>>> a
<CDLL '/opt/homebrew/lib/libmpich.dylib', handle 9b12d7c0 at 0x100a65a00>

